# Storing the value of "findOne" and inserting the returned value using "find" in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to convert a [MongoDB GeoSpatial query](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/#find-all-restaurants-in-the-neighborhood) into Mongoose, but I am not having any luck. The MongoDB query looks like the following:

`var neighborhood = db.neighborhoods.findOne( { geometry: { $geoIntersects: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ] } } } } )`

Where the value of the neighborhood is then inserted within the `$geometry` query of the restaurants.

`db.restaurants.find( { location: { $geoWithin: { $geometry: neighborhood.geometry } } } )`

Then you'll get all the restaurants within the neighborhood.

So, what I have come up with is the following using Mongoose and Express, which is obviously wrong and is just my translation of the MongoDB query.

```
exports.getRestaurantInNeighborhood = function(req, res, next) {

  var geojsonPoint = {type: 'Point', coordinates: [-73.93414657, 40.82302903]};
  var neighborhood = Neighborhood.findOne({geometry: {$geoIntersects: {$geometry: geojsonPoint}}})

  Restaurant.find({location: { $geoWithin: { $geometry: neighborhood.geometry } } } )
  .then(function(data) {
    res.json(data);
  }, function(err) {
    next(err);
  });
}
```

I believe that it's not working because I am not getting the value of `neighborhood` by the time `Restaurant` returns the data, which is giving me the error that there is no `geometry` object in `neighborhood`. Thus, nothing is returning from `neighborhood`.

Any help on solving this issue is appreciated.

**Update:**

What I have come up with, which works, is the following:

```
exports.getRestaurantInNeighborhood = function(req, res, next) {

  var geojsonPoint = {type: 'Point', coordinates: [-73.93414657, 40.82302903]};
  Neighborhood.findOne({geometry: {$geoIntersects: {$geometry: geojsonPoint}}}, function(err, data) {
  }).then(function(data) {
    Restaurant.find({location: { $geoWithin: { $geometry: data.geometry } } })
    .then(function(data) {
      res.json(data);
    }, function(err) {
      next(err);
    });
  });
}
```

However, I am not sure if this is optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on your update, there's no need to specify rejection handlers for each promise and you shouldn't do it. Just chain your promises properly and handle the errors at the end. Any errors will get propagated through the whole chain to the catch() block.

```
exports.getRestaurantInNeighborhood = function (req, res, next) {

    var geojsonPoint = {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [-73.93414657, 40.82302903]
    };

    return Neighborhood
        .findOne({
            geometry: {
                $geoIntersects: {
                    $geometry: geojsonPoint
                }
            }
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            // Make sure there is a return.
            return Restaurant.find({
                location: {
                    $geoWithin: {
                        $geometry: data.geometry
                    }
                }
            });
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            // This gets called if there are no errors.
            res.json(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // Here you handle errors. or you can call next(err) and
            // handle it in a middleware.
            console.warn(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would I need that first return though? From my understanding, `Neighborhood` would automatically fire when the main function is called.

Comment: You wouldn't, just something I always do because it males the intention of the code clearer to me.